# How to remove force list-style-type: disc from community builder HTML editor?

Tags: community, community-builder

it is getting added by default. Tried adding list-style: none !important and list-style-type: none!important

Comment: can you add Image what exactly you want?

Comment: i want to remove the bullets from the list